# spoofing different methods within same form based on current route name in laravel

Tags: laravel, forms, laravel-blade

So on a form I want to change the form spoofing method between PUT and POST **depending on current route name**.

in other words:

- when the route name is equal to *'users.create'* , then put @method('POST') above the form,
- and when route name is equal to *'users.update'* , then put @method('PUT') above the form.

Here's my blade file:

```
<form action="{{ Route::currentRouteName() == 'users.create' ? route('users.store') : route('users.update', $user) }}" method="POST">

    @csrf

    @php
    if (Route::currentRouteName() == 'users.create')
        @method('POST')
    else
        @method('PUT')
    @endphp

    email:
    <input type="email" name="email">

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

form action part works fine, but form spoofing part doesn't, i have no idea that how can i implement this on a blade file!

can any body help me?

Answer (score 1):

i believe you are using resource route. so for create you need not to spoof as post is used for store. check for just edit route and spoof the method.

```
<form action="{{ Route::currentRouteName() == 'users.create' ? route('users.store') : route('users.update', $user) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @if (Route::currentRouteName() == 'users.edit')
        @method('PUT')  
    @endif
    email:
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```